How can I see how many downloads a model or dataset received on Huggingface in total?
Example: https://huggingface.co/datasets/uonlp/CulturaX/:

The number of downloads only           shows the   last month. How can I see how many downloads a model or dataset received on Huggingface in total?
Assume that I am not the model or dataset owner. (The owner may view the total number of downloads via the model’s “Settings” tab at the bottom of the page.)
